# Angular slickgrid custom date filter not working for date range

Tags: angular, slickgrid, datefilter

In angular slickgrid date range filter not working for single date. I mentioned the issue here which is occurring in slickgrid library example. Please refer this [video](https://www.loom.com/share/4be821aa918e457a995eb98f9193f59a) and [example](https://ghiscoding.github.io/Angular-Slickgrid/#/range)

For these reason, i am trying to create custom filter for date field based on my own requirement. But that filter always returning empty value. I shared my custom date filter class with static date range. Please give the solution for my case.

```
import {
    Column,
    ColumnFilter,
    Filter,
    FilterArguments,
    FilterCallback,
    GridOption,
    OperatorType,
    OperatorString,
    SearchTerm,
} from 'angular-slickgrid';

// using external non-typed js libraries
declare var $: any;

export class CustomDateFilter implements Filter {
    private _clearFilterTriggered = false;
    private $filterElm: any;
    grid: any;
    searchTerms: SearchTerm[];
    columnDef: Column;
    callback: FilterCallback;
    operator: OperatorType | OperatorString = OperatorType.rangeInclusive;

    constructor() { }

    /** Getter for the Column Filter */
    get columnFilter(): ColumnFilter {
        return this.columnDef && this.columnDef.filter || {};
    }

    /** Getter for the Grid Options pulled through the Grid Object */
    get gridOptions(): GridOption {
        return (this.grid && this.grid.getOptions) ? this.grid.getOptions() : {};
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the Filter
     */
    init(args: FilterArguments) {
        this.grid = args.grid;
        this.callback = args.callback;
        this.columnDef = args.columnDef;
        this.searchTerms = args.searchTerms || [];

        // filter input can only have 1 search term, so we will use the 1st array index if it exist
        const searchTerm = (Array.isArray(this.searchTerms) && this.searchTerms[0]) || '';

        // step 1, create HTML string template
        const filterTemplate = this.buildTemplateHtmlString();

        // step 2, create the DOM Element of the filter & initialize it if searchTerm is filled
        this.$filterElm = this.createDomElement(filterTemplate, searchTerm);

        // step 3, subscribe to the keyup event and run the callback when that happens
        this.$filterElm.keyup((e: any) => {
            let value = e && e.target && e.target.value || '';
            if (typeof value === 'string' && this.columnFilter.enableTrimWhiteSpace) {
                value = value.trim();
            }


            /* ################################################### */
            // Static filter range for testing
            var fromDate = new Date(2020, 2, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            var toDate = new Date(2021, 2, 9, 23, 59, 59, 999);
            /* ################################################### */

            if (this._clearFilterTriggered) {
                this.callback(e, { columnDef: this.columnDef, clearFilterTriggered: this._clearFilterTriggered });
                this._clearFilterTriggered = false; // reset flag for next use
                this.$filterElm.removeClass('filled');
            } else {
                value === '' ? this.$filterElm.removeClass('filled') : this.$filterElm.addClass('filled');
                this.callback(e, { columnDef: this.columnDef, searchTerms: [fromDate, toDate] });
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Clear the filter value
     */
    clear() {
        if (this.$filterElm) {
            this._clearFilterTriggered = true;
            this.$filterElm.val('');
            this.$filterElm.trigger('keyup');
        }
    }

    /**
     * destroy the filter
     */
    destroy() {
        if (this.$filterElm) {
            this.$filterElm.off('keyup').remove();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set value(s) on the DOM element
     */
    setValues(values) {
        if (values) {
            this.$filterElm.val(values);
        }
    }

    //
    // private functions
    // ------------------

    /**
     * Create the HTML template as a string
     */
    private buildTemplateHtmlString() {
        let placeholder = (this.gridOptions) ? (this.gridOptions.defaultFilterPlaceholder || '') : '';
        if (this.columnFilter && this.columnFilter.placeholder) {
            placeholder = this.columnFilter.placeholder;
        }
        return `<input type="text" class="form-control search-filter" placeholder="${placeholder}">`;
    }

    /**
     * From the html template string, create a DOM element
     * @param filterTemplate
     */
    private createDomElement(filterTemplate: string, searchTerm?: SearchTerm) {
        const $headerElm = this.grid.getHeaderRowColumn(this.columnDef.id);
        $($headerElm).empty();

        // create the DOM element & add an ID and filter class
        const $filterElm = $(filterTemplate);

        $filterElm.val(searchTerm);
        $filterElm.attr('id', `filter-${this.columnDef.id}`);
        $filterElm.data('columnId', this.columnDef.id);

        // append the new DOM element to the header row
        if ($filterElm && typeof $filterElm.appendTo === 'function') {
            $filterElm.appendTo($headerElm);
        }

        return $filterElm;
    }
}
```

---

Here i provided my dataset and column definition

```
public dataset = [{
    "employee_name": "Abhishek",
    "employee_id": 12394,
    "rating": 4.5,
    "birth_date": new Date(702153000000), // Thu Apr 02 1992 00:00:00
    "joining_date": new Date(1388514600000), // Wed Jan 01 2014 00:00:00
    "created_on": new Date(1585810780143), // Thu Apr 02 2020 12:29:40
    "contact_info": {
        "phone": "044 - 28255955",
        "address": "11, Srinivasa Pillai St, Egmore, Chennai, Tamil Nadu, 600008",
        "mail": "example@example.com"
    }
}]


public columnDefinition: Array < Column > = [{
    id: "birth_date",
    name: "Birth date",
    field: "birth_date",
    sortable: true,
    type: FieldType.date,
    formatter: DateTimeFormatter, // Formatter to convert unix timestamps to user defined formatted date string
    params: {
        dateFormat: this.userDefinedDateFormat
    },
    filterable: true,
    filter: {
        model: new CustomDateFilter() 
    }
}, {
    id: "created_on",
    name: "Created on",
    field: "created_on",
    sortable: true,
    type: FieldType.dateTime,
    formatter: DateTimeFormatter, // Formatter to convert unix timestamps to user defined formatted date string
    params: {
        dateFormat: this.userDefinedDateTimeFormat
    },
    filterable: true,
    filter: {
        model: Filters.dateRange
    }
}]
```

In custom filter, i am passing following searchTerm to FilterCallback

**CustomDateFilter.ts**

```
callback: FilterCallback; // Global variable

// on keyup following code implemented
var fromDate = new Date(1991, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0); // Tue Jan 01 1991 00:00:00
var toDate = new Date(1992, 11, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999); // Thu Dec 31 1992 23:59:59

this.callback(e, { columnDef: this.columnDef, searchTerms: [fromDate, toDate] });
```

My data birth_date field meets the criteria but it returns empty view.

---

Default date range filter only working for range not working for single date. Please refer following images for clear understanding

Fig 1 - Default filter working for date range

[image: Fig 1 - Default filter working for date range]

Fig 2 - Default filter not working for single date

[image: Fig 2 - Default filter not working for single date]

Screenshots taken from https://ghiscoding.github.io/Angular-Slickgrid/#/range

---

**Software Version**

Angular :   7.3.5

Angular-Slickgrid : 2.17.10

TypeScript :    3.1.6

Operating System :  Windows 10

Node :  10.16.3

NPM :   6.9.0

Comment: It looks like you're creating your own Custom Date Filter, it might help getting an answer if you provide what your data looks like (data sample) and what you are typing in the custom input filter. I did not look at the video, since it's a work computer.

Comment: Sample data provided in question. Kindly read the question again.

Comment: looks like regular Date object, so what is the reason to not use the current built-in CompoundDate Filter? Just make sure to specify the `type` and outputType` and it should work as is

Comment: Default date range filter only working for range not working for single date. i attached screenshots in question.

Comment: The `Filters.dateRange` is for a range of dates while `Filters.compoundDate` is for a single date. Just choose the one you depending on your use case

Comment: In my case, I cannot differentiate whether user choosing single date or date range.. Better to have a solution for both cases with single filter model.

Comment: then just use the date range, it also works by clicking on a single date, however you won't get the left-side dropdown to choose the operator (though you can set one in your column definitions).